# How to add two columns and update the CSV in python?

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

I have a question here:

> Write a function named `computed_column` that takes a string as a parameter representing the name of a CSV file with 5 columns in the format `<string>,<int>,<int>,<int>,<int>` and writes a file named `creation.csv` containing all the data from the input file but with a sixth column containing the sum of the values from the third and second columns.

This is what I tried:

```
    import csv
    def computed_column(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile,newline='') as f:
      with open('creation.csv','w',newline='') as f2:
        y=[]
        writer = csv.writer(f2)
        rows = csv.reader(f)
        for row in rows:
          for i in range(0,len(row[1])):
            y.append(int(row[1][i]) + int(row[2][i]))
          writer.writerow(row+y)
```

It writes the original file correctly but gives me wrong output for the sixth column that is to be written.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you **don't** need the inner for-loop. For each row, you simply want to add the values in the second and third column (of *that* row), and insert the sum as the sixth column value. You just need to loop through each row, then use the `row` *index* to access the second and third columns.

Also, your list `y` is growing with each row you process (which adds an additional column each time). I don't think that is your intention. Move this within your for-loop so that it resets to an empty list with each row. Try something like this:

```
def computed_column(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile,newline='') as f:
        with open('creation.csv','w',newline='') as f2:
            writer = csv.writer(f2)
            rows = csv.reader(f)
            for row in rows:
                y=[]
                y.append(int(row[1]) + int(row[2]))
                writer.writerow(row+y)
```